# how can I re-utilize and class on a child theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, theme-options

I want to extend a class that is in a parent theme. For example, breadcrumb.php containing the class `breadcrumb` extended with a child theme file custom_breadcrumb.php with the class `custom_breadcrumb`.  From the child theme, I would like to have the ability of extending the breadcrumb class from the parent theme.

```
 |---The_Parent_theme
 |---------breadcrumb.php
 |---The_child_theme
 |---------cutom_breadcrumb.php
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure if I understand your question. Unless the developer has coded the class with [`final` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php), if you want to extend a class, just [do it](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php).

Comment: but can i  do it from a child theme, do i have scope to do that on the child theme?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible kink is that `functions.php` of child theme is loaded *before* that of parent theme. So you would have to keep that timing in mind.

Outside of that normal PHP mechanics apply, both parent and child theme run in same WP environment.

Of course it somewhat depends on parent theme if class is coded to be convenient to extend and override.